# Holdable web button that does not trigger browser specific action on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari, frontend

I'm trying to make a browser application that requires the user to press and hold a button for periods of time in response to stimuli. I can use any dependencies to do this as I'm just building a webpage as a proof of concept for JS audio lib. I'd like to do this the lightest way possible to not get distracted by (read "have to learn much") frontend whizbang.

Is there any way to prevent mobile OS browsers from opening copy paste options for button text, or link options when setting the attribute `href="#"` on a button.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a CSS only solution, then use `pointer-events: none;` for the element in the `@media` that matches the mobile view.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .class {
     pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

---

jQuery Mobile has a [`taphold`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) event.

> *Triggered after a sustained complete touch event.*

So, I guess, if you use the following code:

```
$("selector").taphold(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The above code executes only on the mobile and here, we are preventing the default action.

Comment: I pasted that into my CSS file and get the same behaviour. Doesn't need to be CSS only solution